# What keyboard shortcuts can I use in MS Office 2010?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office-2010

I work using MS Office 2010, and I want to try and minimize my time on finishing a project with the use of keyboard shortcuts. I already know how to use copy-pasting, so everything else that are possible outside of MS Office shouldn't apply in an answer here.

What keyboard shortcuts can I use for MS Office 2010 and what functions does it do?

Comment: Here is a frequently used list of keyboard shortcuts.  https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/microsoft-office-2010-keyboard-shortcuts/#:~:text=Microsoft%20Office%202010%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts%20%20%20,%20%20Ctrl%2BG%20%2012%20more%20rows%20    You probably need to search for the many keyboard shortcuts that Office uses

Comment: Can you make that an answer?

Comment: I have done that for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of shortcuts that Office 2010 (which I have here in my Windows 7 Virtual machine) as well as other versions.

Here is a frequently used list of keyboard shortcuts.

[Office 2010 Shortcuts](https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/microsoft-office-2010-keyboard-shortcuts/#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20Office%202010%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts%20%20%20,%20%20Ctrl%2BG%20%2012%20more%20rows%20)

| Function | Shortcut |
| --- | --- |
| Copy | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> |
| Cut | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> |
| Find | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> |
| Go To | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> |
| Help | <kbd>F1</kbd> |
| Hyperlink | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> |
| New | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> |
| Open | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> |
| Paste | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> |
| Print | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> |
| Replace | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> |
| Save | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> |
| Select All | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> |
| Spell Check | <kbd>F7</kbd> |
| Undo | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> |
| Redo | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> |